# regex to strip periods between letters

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to search on stackoverflow and via google how to strip all . (periods) from a string, except where between numbers. So far I've had no luck.

I have a bunch of file names like:

```
this.is.a.file.1233
another.cool.file.v1.2.3
oh.wow.this.file.again.v1.2.4
guess.what.v1.2.3.is.now.out
```

However I would like to display them as:

```
this is a file 1233
another cool file v1.2.3
oh wow this file again v1.2.4
guess what v1.2.3 is now out
```

Is this possible using regex? I couldn't figure out how to do it successfully and using a simple method of replacing periods with spaces messes up the look of version numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this pattern with preg_replace:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=[a-z])\.|\.(?=[a-z])~i';
```

and a space as replacement.

or more radical:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=\D)\.|\.(?=\D)~';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use assertions here to match periods that state that at least one non-digit character must appear either before or after the period:

```
(?<=\D)\.|\.(?=\D)
```

You would use it in PHP like this:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/(?<=\D)\.|\.(?=\D)/', ' ', $str);
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/3mT2sB) that this prints:

```
this is a file 1233
another cool file v1.2.3
oh wow this file again v1.2.4
guess what v1.2.3 is now out
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a pattern like this: `/\.(?![0-9])|(?<![0-9])\./`, and replace with `' '`

In code, that would look like this:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/\.(?![0-9])|(?<![0-9])\./', ' ', $filename);
```

1. Basically, we're looking for two options `/something|something/`.
2. The first option is a period that is not followed by a number. We use a negative lookahead to check for this: `\.(?![0-9])`
3. The second option is a period that is not preceeded by a number. We use a negative lookbehind for this: `(?<![0-9])\.`

If either matches, then we know that the period isn't surrounded by numbers, and we can replace it. Because we're using lookaheads and lookbehinds, it's only the period that is actually matched, and we can just replace it with a single space.

Given your examples, this will produce the following:

```
this is a file 1233  
another cool file v1.2.3  
oh wow this file again v1.2.4  
guess what v1.2.3 is now out
```